# MongoDb: Query document based on calculation for each document

Tags: mongodb

I want to query a document from a MongoDB database where the condition is the outcome  of a given calculation. I don't know if this is understandable, an analog SQL query might help:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks AS t WHERE t.lastRun < (NOW() - t.maxAge)
```

Each tasks has a maxAge field which determines how often a task should run. If the maxAge is reached, the query should return that task which is then executed.

Because I lack the vocabulary to describe such a query it's hard to find anything about this topic. Please be forgiving if this is mentioned somewhere. :-)

My first reflex was: Let's map the whole collection to contain the calculated threshold for each task, but this seems a bit too much for such a simple query. I hope this isn' t the only solution to this. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using the $where is that it can't be indexed and there are currently issues with running javascript queries on the server, because the javascript engine is single threaded.

A better approach in this case would be  to

re-write:t.lastRun < (NOW() - t.maxAge)
to:      (t.lastRun + t.maxAge) < NOW()

The sum of t.lastRun and t.maxAge would be calculated and stored in an additional field upon insertion.  Thus the resulting query would only require a single comparison.

Comment: Just to add to what Matt says, modifying the schema to have a single computed field will not only allow the query to be answered using a simple query but this computed field can also be indexed for faster comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
db.tasks.insert({lastRun:new ISODate(), maxAge:100});

db.tasks.find({ $where: "this.maxAge < (new ISODate()-this.lastRun)"});
```